# Video Quality - Azure Communication Services

Tags: azure-communication-services

The video quality of the cameras is pretty bad, I didn't find anything in the documentation giving me the option to change it.

```
const cameraPermissionState: PermissionState = await this.deviceManager!.getPermissionState('Camera');
this.localVideoStream = new LocalVideoStream(this.deviceManager?.getCameraList()[0]!);
await this.call?.startVideo(this.localVideoStream!);
await this.renderLocalVideo(this.localVideoStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft support just informed that they are supporting only 1x1 video call. They hope to release a new version in February 21 to handle more than 2 people sharing video at the same time.